# how to find name which start with capital letter in sql server

Tags: sql

I want to find the values which starts which starts with capital letters

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?  We need to know this in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ASCII and solution will be:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ASCII(LEFT(yourColumn, 1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90
```

More about ASCII table you can find here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Works like a charm :D